# Extract value from string in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

My logs are added in kibana, the logs are in string format. 
Consider a log line is like 'Total Execution time 1s' I need to extract 1 from this line and put this in some graph or sum it.

Can someone please guide how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Manipulation of String can be done b Logstash using GROK input filter. Or at Elasticsearch Ingest node using similar filter.

**More info**: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html

Once the String is parse and stored in an appropriate field, you can visualize it on Kibana. Kibana itself cannot parse a field.